# DataTables dataTables_filter class not visible in FF

Tags: javascript, datatables

http://communitychessclub.com/games.php

The dataTables search function works fine in Chrome, but the input characters are invisible in FireFox. Also the Console inspector in FireFox reveals: `ReferenceError: table is not defined`  Is that critical?

```
<div id="cccr_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
    <label>Search:<input type="search" class="" placeholder="" aria-controls="cccr"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined very large padding in `screen.css:190` and it makes the text disappear when combined with `box-sizing: border-box;` in `foundation.css:2741`. Add the following CSS rule:

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter input[type="search"]{
  padding:0 0.5em; 
}
```

Regarding the JavaScript error, you need to set `"responsive": true`, as shown below:

```
  $('#cccr').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
       { "width": "50%", "Date": 0 }
    ],
    "order": [
        [0, "desc"],
        [2, "asc"],
        [1, "asc"]
    ],
    "aaSorting": [],
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bLengthChange": true,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bSort": true,
    "bInfo": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sScrollY": "25rem",
    "bStateSave": false,
    "responsive": true,
    "bAutoWidth":false,
    "autoWidth": true
});
```

You can remove these lines:

```
var oTable = $('#cccr').dataTable(); 
oTable.fnFilter('');
new $.fn.dataTable.Responsive(table);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!